# Convert Linq to Sql Expression to Expression Tree

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, expression, expression-trees

Can anyone convert this simple LINQ-to-SQL to an Expression Tree:

```
List<Region> lst = (from r in dc.Regions
                    where r.RegionID > 2 && r.RegionDescription.Contains("ern")
                    select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var query = dc.Regions.AsQueryable();

ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Region), "region");

Expression id = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, "RegionID");
Expression two = Expression.Constant(2);
Expression e1 = Expression.GreaterThan(id, two);

Expression description = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, "RegionDescription");
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof(string)});
Expression ern = Expression.Constant("ern",typeof(string));
Expression e2 = Expression.Call(description, method, ern);

Expression e3 = Expression.And(e1, e2);

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Where",
                new Type[] { query.ElementType },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<Region, bool>>(e3, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
var results = query.Provider.CreateQuery<Region>(whereCallExpression);

List<Region> lst = results.ToList();
```

And to select just `RegionID` from  the result set do the following:

```
MethodCallExpression selectExpression = Expression.Call(
                                typeof(Queryable),                                
                                "Select",
                                new[]{ typeof(Region), typeof(int)},
                                whereCallExpression, 
                                Expression.Lambda<Func<Region, int>>(id, pe));

var regionIDsQuery = query.Provider.CreateQuery<int>(selectExpression);

List<int> regionIDs = regionIDsQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Alot.It's very useful.can you introduce some article about Expression Tree?How you being master in Expression Tree?Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post and replace "widget" with "ern".can you show me what should I do if I want just select "RegionID".thanks

Comment: @Nima Glad I could help. Thanks for saying that but I'm no master of `Expression Trees`. They're just an interesting structure that I work with to gain a better understanding of `Linq` in general. I recommend reading the documentation of course, but also writing some standard `Linq` queries and then examining their `Expression` properties. Little by little this will help you understand the underlying mechanics. I'll update my answer to include the `Select` call.

Comment: @Nima Here's a pretty good example article to get you started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx. I also recommend downloading `LinqPad` if you haven't already. It really speeds up the learning process by making experimentation so easy. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi friend.I write your select call statment for "Order" table but I can't select my desire column such as: OrderID,OrderDate,ShipAddress,RequiredDate.May you help me please?Thanks