# Expression Tree as part of a Property

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm drawing inspiration from this question:

[Convert Linq to Sql Expression to Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225416/convert-linq-to-sql-expression-to-expression-tree)

The original poster asked how to convert this to an Expression tree and got a good answer which can be seen in the above link.

```
List<Region> lst = (from r in dc.Regions
                    where r.RegionID > 2 && r.RegionDescription.Contains("ern")
                    select r).ToList();
```

How would I got about making a property with a get method that returns a bool that uses the ExpressionTree?  I'd like to be able to do something like this (obviously I don't need the `== true`):

```
List<Region> lst = (from r in dc.Regions
                    where (r.AwesomeProperty == true)
                    select r).ToList();
```

How would I go about defining `AwesomeProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would define `AwesomeProperty` just like any other property on your LINQ to SQL object. Assuming it is typed as `bool` (since you compare it to `true`), you would build the `Where` query like this:

```
// Build the parameter to the where clause predicate and access AwesomeProperty

var regionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Region), "region");

var awesomeProperty = Expression.Property(regionParameter, "AwesomeProperty");

// Build the where clause predicate using the AwesomeProperty access

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Region, bool>>(awesomeProperty);

// Get the table, which serves as the base query

var table = dc.Regions.AsQueryable();

// Call the Where method using the predicate and the table as the base query

var whereCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new[] { table.ElementType },
    table.Expression,
    predicate);

// Get an IQueryable<Region> which executes the where call on the table

var query = table.Provider.CreateQuery<Region>(whereCall);

var results = query.ToList();
```