# Dynamically building an expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm following this excellent example: [Convert Linq to Sql Expression to Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225416/convert-linq-to-sql-expression-to-expression-tree)

In my case I'm trying to build an expression tree where the type to be filtered is only known at run time, and is expressed as a string. In the above example the type *Region* is already known and typed directly:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Region), "region");
```

In my application I've been able to rewrite this as:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(Type.GetType("mystring"), "listData");
```

My stumbling block is this from the example:

```
MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { query.ElementType },
            query.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Region, bool>>(e3, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
var results = query.Provider.CreateQuery<Region>(whereCallExpression);
```

In these two lines *Region* is directly typed. Is there a way of dynamically using a string "Region" to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, but you'll have to understand the implications. The type name `Region` is the compile time type.  With it, you can generate a strongly typed query.  However, since you don't have the type at compile time, you *can* still generate a query, but it won't be strongly typed.

You can generate an lambda expression of unknown compile time type by using the non-generic overloads.  Likewise with the `CreateQuery()` method.

Here's two versions of the same query which checks if some property value matches a given value. One is generic and the other is not.

The generic version implicitly takes the type from the type of the query.

```
public IQueryable<TSource> PropertyEqualsValue<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> query,
        string propertyName, object value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(param, propertyName),
        Expression.Constant(value)
    );
    var expr = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new[] { typeof(TSource) },
        query.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, param)
    );
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(expr);
}
```

```
var query = PropertyEqualsValue(SomeTable, "SomeColumn", "SomeValue");
```

While the other the type is taken from the provided `typeName`.  Note that when the query is created, we cannot provide the type, since we don't know what the type is at compile time.

```
public IQueryable PropertyEqualsValue(IQueryable query,
        Type type, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(param, propertyName),
        Expression.Constant(value)
    );
    var expr = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new[] { type },
        query.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda(body, param)
    );
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery(expr);
}
```

```
var type = Type.GetType("Some.Type.Name");
var query = PropertyEqualsValue(SomeTable, type, "SomeColumn", "SomeValue");
```

Comment: any idea how to pass StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase to Expression.Equal call?

Comment: `Expression.Equal()` corresponds to the use of the `==` operator. You wouldn't be able to add that parameter. You would need to generate an expression equivalent to `stringVar.Equals(otherStringVar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` or using the static `String.Equals(stringVar, otherStringVar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.