# Successive LINQ queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to build a LINQ query to query against a large SQL table (7M+ entries) of `Documents`.

Each document has many `DocumentFields` :

[image: Simplified UML]

My goal is to apply successive filters (from 0 to ~10 filters) on the `value` field of `DocumentField`:

Here is an example of the filters I want to apply:

```
[
  {fieldId: 32, value: "CET20533"},
  {fieldId: 16, value: "882341"},
  {fieldId: 12, value: "101746"}
]
```

What I want is to retrieve every document in my database that matches all of the filters. For the previous example, I want all documents that have a value of CET20533 for the field with the Id "32", the value 882341 for the field with the Id 16, and so on.

I had a first approach :

```
List<MyFilter> filters = ... // Json deserialization
db.Documents.Where(document =>
  filters.All(filter =>
     document.DocumentFields.Any(documentField =>
        documentField.Id == filter.Id
        && documentField.Value == filter.Value)));
```

This approach doesn't work : my `filters` List isn't a primitive type, and therefore cannot be used in a LINQ query.

I had a second approach, which didn't throw an error at me, but only applied 1 filter :

```
var result = db.Documents.Select(d => d);
foreach (var filter in filters) {
  var id = filter.Id;
  var value = filter.Value;

  result = result.Where(document => document.DocumentFields.Any(documentField =>
    documentField.Id == id
    && documentField.Value == value));
}
```

The problem with this approach is, I believe, some sort of a concurrency problem. I applied a simple pause `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in each iteration of the foreach to test, and it seems to work.

Questions :

- How to remove the pause and still not have concurrency problems ?
- Is there a better way to build my query ?

**EDIT :**

For more clarity, here is an actual example of a document that matches the previous filters example :

[image: Example document]

Comment: Are you sure that filters.All doesn't change your IQueriable to IEnumerable? Check the result with the profiler. I would suggest to parse filters and add it to query as Expressions

Comment: As soon as `db.Documents` is `IQueryable<T>`, the second approach with chaining multiple `Where` should work - I don't see any concurrency issues there since it's just building a query. Of course I'm assuming you use `==` in both places (`=` is being a typo).

Comment: The problem with the multiple Where is that I don't know in advance how many filters there will be : it can be 0, it can also be 10. So I can't write .Where(filter1).Where(filter2).Where(filter3). The foreach actually only builds the query, as you said, so I don't see either why it doesn't work without the pause ...
EDIT : It seems to work without the Sleep now, I guess I made a mistake earlier ?

Comment: you can build you IQueriable in a loop like `foreach(filter in filters) query = query.Where(GetExpr(fiter));`

Comment: @ASpirin — Nice trick! I'll have to keep that one in mind.

Comment: Indeed, it is the same as what I did but way cleaner ! I just have to learn how to build Expression Trees I guess.

Comment: That is not so complex and a lot of materials are accessible

Comment: The `DocumentFields` have no `.Value` in your JSON example. So how can you write `documentField.Value == value`?

Comment: @tinudu replying quite some time later, but the `.Value` in the example code here was a simplification of the actual model.

I had 3 "Value" fields: `StringValue`, `FloatValue` and `DateTimeValue`, and only one of them would be populated.

If I remember correctly, I replaced `documentField.Value` with the appropriate `documentField.FloatValue`, `documentField.DateValue` etc.

I was able to know in advance the type associated to each ID (e.g. fieldId `32` would always be `string`, so I could look at StringValue only).

Also, I would probably design the data structure differently today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Build expression based on your filters and append each in where separately (or not if you can manage it)

```
db.Documents.Where(ex1).Where(ex2)...
```

see [e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386819/dynamically-building-an-expression-tree) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or simple case: Start from DocumentFields and retrieve Related Documents. operation Contains works for simple types. that will also simplier in case of building of expression

Answer (score 1):

Quite convinced that your data model is too generic. It will hurt you in terms of program clarity and performance.

But let's go with it for this answer, which I took as a challenge in expression building. The goal is to get a nice queryable that honors the filters on the data server side.

Here's the data model I used, which I think closely matches yours:

```
public sealed class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<DocumentField> Fields { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DocumentField
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public float? FloatValue { get; set; }
    // more typed vales here
}
```

First, I implement conveniance functions to create predicates for individual fields of individual field types:

```
public static class DocumentExtensions
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo _piFieldId = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)((Expression<Func<DocumentField, int>>)(f => f.Id)).Body).Member;

    private static Expression<Func<DocumentField, bool>> FieldPredicate<T>(int fieldId, T value, Expression<Func<DocumentField, T>> fieldAccessor)
    {
        var pField = fieldAccessor.Parameters[0];
        var xEqualId = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(pField, _piFieldId), Expression.Constant(fieldId));
        var xEqualValue = Expression.Equal(fieldAccessor.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T)));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<DocumentField, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(xEqualId, xEqualValue), pField);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// f => f.<see cref="DocumentField.Id"/> == <paramref name="fieldId"/> && f.<see cref="DocumentField.StringValue"/> == <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<DocumentField, bool>> FieldPredicate(int fieldId, string value) => FieldPredicate(fieldId, value, f => f.StringValue);

    /// <summary>
    /// f => f.<see cref="DocumentField.Id"/> == <paramref name="fieldId"/> && f.<see cref="DocumentField.FloatValue"/> == <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<DocumentField, bool>> FieldPredicate(int fieldId, float? value) => FieldPredicate(fieldId, value, f => f.FloatValue);

    // more overloads here
}
```

Usage:

```
var fieldPredicates = new[] {
        DocumentExtensions.FieldPredicate(32, "CET20533"), // f => f.Id == 32 && f.StringValue == "CET20533"
        DocumentExtensions.FieldPredicate(16, "882341"),
        DocumentExtensions.FieldPredicate(12, 101746F) // f => f.Id == 12 && f.FloatValue == 101746F
};
```

Second, I implement an extension method `HavingAllFields`(also in `DocumentExtensions`) that creates an `IQueryable<Document>` where all of the field predicates are satisfied by at least one field:

```
    private static readonly MethodInfo _miAnyWhere = ((MethodCallExpression)((Expression<Func<IEnumerable<DocumentField>, bool>>)(fields => fields.Any(f => false))).Body).Method;
    private static readonly Expression<Func<Document, IEnumerable<DocumentField>>> _fieldsAccessor = doc => doc.Fields;

    /// <summary>
    /// <paramref name="documents"/>.Where(doc => doc.Fields.Any(<paramref name="fieldPredicates"/>[0]) && ... )
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<Document> HavingAllFields(this IQueryable<Document> documents, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<DocumentField, bool>>> fieldPredicates)
    {
        using (var e = fieldPredicates.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) return documents;

            Expression predicateBody = Expression.Call(_miAnyWhere, _fieldsAccessor.Body, e.Current);
            while (e.MoveNext())
                predicateBody = Expression.AndAlso(predicateBody, Expression.Call(_miAnyWhere, _fieldsAccessor.Body, e.Current));
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Document, bool>>(predicateBody, _fieldsAccessor.Parameters);
            return documents.Where(predicate);
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
var documents = (new[]
{
    new Document
    {
        Id = 1,
        Fields = new[]
        {
            new DocumentField { Id = 32, StringValue = "CET20533" },
            new DocumentField { Id = 16, StringValue = "882341" },
            new DocumentField { Id = 12, FloatValue = 101746F },
        }
    },
    new Document
    {
        Id = 2,
        Fields = new[]
        {
            new DocumentField { Id = 32, StringValue = "Bla" },
            new DocumentField { Id = 16, StringValue = "882341" },
            new DocumentField { Id = 12, FloatValue = 101746F },
        }
    }
}).AsQueryable();
var matches = documents.HavingAllFields(fieldPredicates).ToList();
```

Matches document 1, but not 2.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this: put all your desired Id's for your filter into a list, then use `contains`.

```
List<int> myDesiredIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
db.documents.Where(x=>myDesiredIds.Contains(x.DocumentId));
```

Comment: Actually, every document has every field id. What is important is the value associated with the filter id. That was not clear in my question.

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon — Expanding on Robert's answer: `db.documents.Where(x=>myDesiredIds.Contains(x.DocumentId) && x=>myDesiredValues.Contains(x.DocumentValue));`

Comment: @InteXX: That would lose some of the information. E.g. the OP does not want an element with fieldid 32 and value 882341; which your suggestion will still include because it omits the pairing.

Comment: The question is more complex than your answer though. It's not just about a list of ints, it's about a list of _combined criteria_. If the OP was working with a list of ints, he would not have received the error that he mentions (*"my filters List isn't a primitive type, and therefore cannot be used in a LINQ query"*)

Comment: Thanks, InteXX, my answer is a bit more universal to get the general idea across. The thing is that this construction feels a bit strange at first because it is assembled reversely (in a way), but once you get used to it you start using it everywhere.

Comment: Well my problem here is that I want documents that have EVERY `DocumentField` that match my filters. Starting with DocumentFields I could easily get the Documents that match ANY of my filters. A filter being the pair of `DocumentField.Id` and `DocumentField.Value`

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon — If you weren't facing the scale that you are, you could pull all documents that meet the first filter from the database, and then for the rest of the filters remove from the in-memory list those that don't meet the filter. But that scale is a killer. ASpirin's answer seems correct in concept, but you're likely going to have varying numbers of filters.

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon — *"Actually, every document has every field id."* I believe this may lead to your answer. By *"filter id"*, do you mean `StringValue` from the JSON above? If so, disregard `FieldId` and let `StringValue` be your list of primitives.

Comment: What I mean is that every document of type 3 (see the JSON above) will have a value for the fields 12, 19, 23, 16, 32 ... In this example, the type 3 is an "Delivery Note" and the field 12 is "Delivery number", the field 19 is "Order number", the field 32 is "UX" and so on. My query in english would be : Find all the Delivery notes that have a delivery number of 101746, for the UX "CET20533", and the Invoiced customer "882341". More precisions : Filter id == `FieldId`, the values are stored either in StringValue, FloatValue or DateTimeValue (I know that in advance)

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon — It looks like you've found your answer with ASpirin. Good enough; I like his solution as well. Just a quick reminder: I only saw your reply by accident, as it didn't include an @ notifier to make sure the note made it to my inbox.

Comment: It's not about filtering by `Document.DocumentId`at all. Don't see how this is an answer to the question.